# Sintaxe para colocar mais de uma id para pegar determinados produtos do banco

Tags: php

Queria pegas mais de uma id do banco, pois só consigo puxar apenas uma. 
Acho que deve ser a sintaxe que esta errada.`

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM camiseta_Masc WHERE id =1,2,3";
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é erro na sintaxe.

Uma solução é esta:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM camiseta_Masc WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920210/1)**.

Erros desta natureza podem ser resolvidos com uma leitura no manual da linguagem.

Se não existisse o `IN`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM camiseta_Masc WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3";
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920210/2)**.

Só de curiosidade, o `IN` poderia ser usado "ao contrário" se quisesse achar um valor em mais de um campo, em vez de mais de um valor em um campo:

```
SELECT nome WHERE 3107 IN ( codigo, codigo_master );
```